Different bases of vector spaces of symmetric polynomials
Fix some positive integer $N$ and consider the vector space $V$ of symmetric polynomials of weight $N$, for simplicity in $N$ variables. We have different bases for $V$:
(1) - the $\sigma_{j_1}\dots\sigma_{j_n}$ where the $\sigma_{j_i}$s are the elementary symmetric polynomials;
(2) - the $P_{j_1}\dots P_{j_n}$ with the $P_{j_i}$s being the power sums; and
(3) - the monomial symmetric polynomials of weight $N$.
The power sum $P_N = X_1^N+\dots X_N^N$ may of course be expressed as a linear combination of the $\sigma_{j_1}\dots\sigma_{j_n}$s. Let the coefficient of $\sigma_{j_1}\dots\sigma_{j_n}$ be $a_{(j_1,\dots,j_n)}$. These coefficients can easily be established by the Newton identities. The partition $(j_1,\dots,j_n)$ of $N$ also corresponds to a monomial symmetric polynomial given by the sum of the monomials $X_{k_1}^{j_1}\dots X_{k_n}^{j_n}$ with the $k_i$ being distinct. Once again express $X_{k_1}^{j_1}\dots X_{k_n}^{j_n}$ as a linear combination of the $\sigma_{j_1}\dots\sigma_{j_n}$s. Denote the coefficient of the $\sigma_N=X_1\dots X_n$ by $b_{(j_1,\dots,j_n)}$. Do the $a$s and $b$s always coincide?
As an example, the $P_4 = \dots + 2\sigma_2^2 + \dots-4\sigma_4$ so $a_{(2,2)}=2$. The partition $(2,2)$ corresponds to the monomial sum $M_{(2,2)}=X_1^2X_2^2+X_1^2X_3^2+X_1^2X_4^2+X_2^2X_3^2+X_2^2X_4^2+X_3^2X_4^2 = \frac{1}{2}[(X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2+X_4^2)^2-(X_1^4+X_2^4+X_3^4+X_4^4)]$
Within the outermost bracket, the former term when expressed in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials will not involve $\sigma_4$, and the latter of course yields $4\sigma_4$ so $b_{(2,2)}=2$.
